# Many WAR's and one common operation

Tags: jakarta-ee, war, servlet-filters, modularity

I have to modify content of many WAR start pages to add some functionality. I can't use filters to modify cause filter needs to be placed in Web Archive. The same with servlet etc. Any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the global web.xml of the container. This will affect all applications:

```
This document defines default values for *all* web applications
loaded into this instance of Tomcat.  As each application is
deployed, this file is processed, followed by the
"/WEB-INF/web.xml" deployment descriptor from your own applications.
```

Alternatively you could implement a [Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html) which you'll install in server.xml for a specific host (which will be running all the wars).

Comment: OK but how can I access my EJB? To process all start pages I need an access to my EJB. I forgot to mention that all my WARs, ejb jars etc. are packaged in EAR.